# Detecting the elements from the image in sequence

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

I've attached a sample screenshot with below link, and based on that screenshot, I'm looking to get the results in JSON format.

The expected JSON structure is as follows:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19KHUchuFa6zhHevaP0oxZebQhk0NeARl/view?usp=sharing

For Group1:
First Row: `{"name": "First Name", "Type": "Input"}`
Second Row: `{"Day": "DropDown", "Month": "DropDown", "Year": "DropDown"}`
For Group2:
Third Row: `{"Id": "", "Social Security Number": "", "9 digit Number": ""}`

Could you please help me convert the screenshot data into this JSON format?

I have tried detecting the elements from image but the issue with sequence, like in first row which element are there and second row which elements are there like I am expecting output.